# Pinescript taking extended hours as High, low, open and close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In tradingview, while writing a pine script for Previous day Open, High, Close and Low (OHCL) values. it is considering Extended Session values.

How to exclude them to get the regular session OHCLs.

For Ex : Actual marker hours start at 9:15AM, so the opening price should be of 9:15AM open, but the new version of script is considering 9:00 AM open value.
same for Closing value as well. it is considering 3:30pm candle closing value as closing value.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Previous Day High and Low", shorttitle="PDHL", overlay=true)

D_High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high) 
D_Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High", style = plot.style_cross, color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low", style = plot.style_cross, color=color.red,linewidth=2)
```